# Can not hide with JQuery "View All Site Content" for NT AUTHORITY\authenticated visitors in SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

My option is to use JQuery to hide the "View All Site Content" link.

The result when I use this code is that the link will be hidden for *Administrators* but not hidden for visitors with NT AUTHORITY\authenticated rights. How can I hide "View All Site Content" also for NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users?

`$('#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4_idNavLinkViewAllV4').hide();`

Comment: Does it have a different ID when you're logged in with regular users?

Comment: this is the ID in both cases: ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4_idNavLinkViewAllV4

Comment: What do you get if you do `alert($("#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4_idNavLinkViewAllV4").length);` ?

Comment: Then that element doesn't exist, and you're probably referring to an ID not existing (maybe it's inside an iframe?). If you use chrome (I'm unsure if sharepoint works with anything else than IE, but I hope it does), then you can hit CTRL+SHIFT+J and execute `$("#elementid").length` in the JS console until you get a `1`.

Comment: It looks like some other part of code does not have access rights for NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users and  that is what causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint 2013**

There are two possibilities that doesn't require code:

- Change the permission level of the visitor group from Read to
- Restricted Read Alternate read permission level of the visitors group
  and remove the base permission View Application Pages from the Read
  Permission level.

**SharePoint Online**

The solution I came up require the usage of the control SPSecurityTrimmerControl. This is a control contained into the assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls that does the security trimming of the child controls inside it. It will basically hide all its content from users that won't meet a given security definition.

Open the master page in edit mode and edit the MenuItemTemplate related to the Site Content by moving it inside a SPSecurityTrimmerControl control.

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl 
  runat="server" 
  Permissions="AddListItems" 
  PermissionContext="CurrentItem" 
  PermissionMode="Any"><SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" 
    id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_15%>"Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=43"MenuGroupId="200"Sequence="240"UseShortId="true"ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/viewlsts.aspx"PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"PermissionMode="Any" />
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

PS. This solution won't restrict the access by URL.